# Como habilitar session_start() en subdominio?

Tags: php

Hola compañeros tengo un problema, resulta que en mi dominio principal [www.midominio.com](http://www.midominio.com) tengo un inicio de sesión que me funciona perfecto pero debo de tener otro login en un subdominio el cual no me inicia la sesión.

Mi pregunta es como hago para que en mi subdominio pueda tener una sesión independiente de mi dominio principal. Muchas gracias un saludo :D

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente no tienes nada o casi nada personalizado respecto a las sesiones. Esto efectivamente puede resultar en que se compartan sesiones entre aplicaciones PHP diferentes (si ninguna lo personaliza y usan los valores por defecto del servidor).

Siendo así, una solución rápida es personalizar la ubicación donde quieres que se guarden los archivos de sesión. Al tenerlos en ubicaciones diferentes, ya no se compartirán las sesiones.

Eso se hace con la función `session_save_path`:

```
session_save_path('/ruta/sesiones');
```

Recuerda además que dispones de muchas funciones para personalizar el uso de las sesiones en PHP. Incluso puedes optar por guardar las sesiones en base de datos en vez de en archivos.

Comment: Hola José, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, soy un poco nuevo con esto de las sesiones tienes alguna documentacion de la cual me pueda guiar?

Comment: Y además tengo un pequeño problema es que en el subdominio ni siquiera inicia la sesión no se porque :c

Comment: Simplemente busca "session_save_path php" y te saldrá la documentación oficial de PHP, y ahí te enlazará con otras funciones para manejo de funciones en PHP, por si te llaman la atención. Sobre que ni siquiera inicia la sesión, por favor, amplía la información editando la pregunta. Muestra cómo sabes que no está iniciando la sesión, y cómo estás intentando iniciar la sesión. Recuerda que no puedes hacer `session_start()` después de haber enviado ya alguna salida, lo que incluye cabeceras (header). Y ¿has mirado el log de errores? quiźa ahí hay algo que ayude a depurar.